# Send CSV in Body via Falcon

Tags: python-3.x, falconframework

I'm trying to send CSV via GET request in Falcon. I don't know where to begin.

Below is my code:

```
class LogCSV(object):
"""CSV generator.

This class responds to  GET methods.
"""
def on_get(self, req, resp):
    """Generates CSV for log."""

    mylist = [
        'one','two','three'
    ]

    myfile = open("testlogcsv.csv", 'w')
    wr = csv.writer(myfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    wr.writerow(mylist)

    resp.status = falcon.HTTP_200
    resp.content_type = 'text/csv'
    resp.body = wr
```

I don't want spoonfeeding, please let me know what I should read/watch to help solve this.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [`Response.stream`](http://falcon.readthedocs.org/en/stable/api/request_and_response.html#Response.stream) attribute. It must be set to a file-like object (an object with a `read()` method) before returning.

So first, you should write your CSV to this object, and then give it to Falcon. In your case:

```
resp.content_type = 'text/csv'
# Move the file pointer to the beginning
myfile.seek(0)
resp.stream = myfile
```

Remember to move the file pointer to the beginning using `seek(0)` , so Falcon can read it.

If your file is ephemeral and small enough to be stored in memory, you can use a memory-file like [`BytesIO`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.BytesIO) instead of a normal file. It behaves like a normal file but is never written to the file system.

```
myfile = BytesIO()
wr = csv.writer(myfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

...

resp.content_type = 'text/csv'
# Move the file pointer to the beginning
myfile.seek(0)
resp.stream = myfile
```

;)